# How to use nextPageToken in Google Apps Reseller API?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-reseller-api

I am writing a simple Java application that fetches all customer subscriptions from Google Apps Reseller using the Reseller API. However I am stuck at paging through the results as the max size is 100 per page and I cannot figure out the next page token. Here is the code so far. How do I use the setNextPageToken() and print all of the results?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleApiUtil.getCredentials();

        Reseller service = new Reseller.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
                .setApplicationName("ResellerDemo").build();


        boolean allResultsRead = false;
        String nextPageToken = null;
        while (!allResultsRead) {
            Subscriptions result = service.subscriptions().list()   
                    .execute();
            List<Subscription> subscriptions = result.getSubscriptions();
            nextPageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
            if (subscriptions == null || subscriptions.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No subscriptions found.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Subscriptions:");
                for (Subscription sub : subscriptions) {
                    System.out.printf("%s (%s, %s)\n",
                            sub.getCustomerId(),
                            sub.getSkuId(),                               
                            sub.getPlan().getCommitmentInterval());
                }
            }
            if (result.getNextPageToken() == null) {
                allResultsRead = true;

            } else {
                result.setNextPageToken(result.getNextPageToken());

            }

        }
```

Comment: In the request you are sending, for example,GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/subscriptions?customerNamePrefix=prefix &pageToken=token&maxResults=max number, specify max results to larger number. Then for each page you will get 100 results. API will automatically generate next page token. Note  that the number of results should be greater than 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. When you implement the real thing, make sure you have retry with exponential back off.

```
public void retrieveAll() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleApiUtil.getCredentials();

    Reseller service = new Reseller.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
            .setApplicationName("ResellerDemo").build();

    String nextPageToken = null;


    do {
        Subscriptions subsList = service.subscriptions().list().setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(100)).setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                .execute();
        printSubscirptions(subsList);

        nextPageToken = subsList.getNextPageToken();

    } while(nextPageToken != null && !"".equals(nextPageToken));


}

private void printSubscirptions(Subscriptions subscriptions){
    System.out.println("Subscriptions:");
    for (Subscription sub : subscriptions.getSubscriptions()) {
        System.out.printf("%s (%s, %s)\n",
                sub.getCustomerId(),
                sub.getSkuId(),
                sub.getPlan().getCommitmentInterval());
    }

}
```